# last three number show using php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i used this code but some thing wrong.
i show only last three number show using php in javascript.

```js
var number = "678342345"
function substr() {
var numbersub = <?php
$rest = substr(number, -3);
echo $rest;
?>
document.getElementById("nember").innerHTML = numbersub;
};
```

```html
<button class="buttonsa" onclick="substr()">Show Number</button>
<br>
<div id="nember"></div>
```

Comment: Replace the php with an example result from the php

Answer (score 2):

```
 var number = "678342345";
```

Thats a variable in javascript (on the client). You can't access it in PHP (on the backend). But you could just do the same you did in php in js:

```
var numbersub = number.substr(-3);
```

Or you have to move `number` to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the the last three number only:

```js
let number = "678342345"
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener('click', function() {
  let str = number.toString();
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = str.substr(str.length-3);;
})
```

```html
<button class="buttonsa" id="mybutton">Show Number</button><br>
<div id="number"></div>
```

If you want to show the number without the last three digits:

```js
let number = "678342345"
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener('click', function() {
  let str = number.toString();
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = str.substr(0, str.length-3);;
})
```

```html
<button class="buttonsa" id="mybutton">Show Number</button><br>
<div id="number"></div>
```

Good luck.